# D3.js From mouse to touch Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to make my visualization Mobile Compatible however I'm struggling with the touch events.

From the following example, I managed to get the event listener working, however I can't get the Div information of the Double Tapped Div (e.g. its ID):
http://bl.ocks.org/jczaplew/7018691

With d3.js dblClick its straightforward, because the this is the clicked element:

```
...
.on("dblclick", doubleClickFunction);
function doubleClickFunction(){
   var id = this.id;
}
```

Any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer. In the example http://bl.ocks.org/jczaplew/7018691 , there is an auxiliar function:

```
d3.selection.prototype.dblTap = function(callback) {
  var last = 0;
  return this.each(function() {
    d3.select(this).on("touchstart", function(e) {
        if ((d3.event.timeStamp - last) < 500) {
          //Touched element
          console.log(this);
          return callback(e);
        }
        last = d3.event.timeStamp;
    });
  });
}
```

If you add the console.log(this) to the running code, you'll see that each time you double tap that the element itself is logged.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the position (i.e; `x`, `y` coordinates) of the double tap? The parameter `e` passed to the callback is always `undefined`.